# cronjob not running in VM

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Script file :

```
#script.sh
#!/BIN/BASH
# To alert whenever lsof crosses 80%

maxlimit=32000
echo 'Max limit is ' $maxlimit
tlimit=$(bc <<< $maxlimit*0.8)
echo 'Treshold limit at 80% ' $tlimit
a=$(lsof | wc -l)
echo 'Current usage ' $a
if [ $(bc <<< "$a > $tlimit") -eq 1 ]
then
        echo 'lsof =' $a 'has exceeded 80% of maximum limit' | /usr/bin/Mail -s "ALERT!!!" "vsp@cisco.com"
fi
```

Next crontab -e

```
* * * * * root  /root/vasanth/lsef/script.sh
```

Scheduled to run every minute 
But not getting any details regarding this

- I run it in a linux terminal in VM
- When I run it manually am getting output
- When loaded in crontab its showing in log that its running every minute

Comment: You shouldn't have the username in a per-user `crontab` file edited with `crontab -e`. That's only done in the system-wide `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: You can't have a line `#script.sh` before the `#!` line, the `#!` line has to be the first line of the file. And `/bin/bash` needs to be lowercase

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Am a newbie
could you explain a lil in detail

Comment: I have tried that too
Took off #script.sh and username "root"
Still isnt working